# How can i make this mysql query work without getting empty results?

Tags: php, mysql, database, mybb

I am having trouble getting teh results i want from this mysql query. And i think the trouble lies in this line of code:

$group="SELECT * from mybb_users where usergroup AND additionalgroups = '$usergroup'";

because i noticed that the additionalgroups column in the database has more than one value separated by a comma(,) whereas the usergroup only has ONE value. Here is a screenshot:

here is an image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HVVN9.jpg

The entire code works perfect if i remove the additionalgroups column from the code and only check the usergroup column, but that is not what i want :( Below is the entire code:

```
// Connect to server and select databse.
mysql_connect("$db_host", "$db_user", "$db_pass")or die("cannot connect to mysql"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

$id=$_GET['lid'];     // Get lid from URL
$usergroup =$_GET['game'];       // Get the usergroup/game from the URL

// Check to see if the user is a VIP Member and fetch them.
$group="SELECT * from mybb_users where usergroup AND additionalgroups = '$usergroup'";
$group2=mysql_query($group) or die("Could not get users");
while($raw=mysql_fetch_array($group2))
{
// Fetch all UserIDs of the VIP members and match them with the UfID (in the userfields table)
$userid = $raw['uid'];
$group3="SELECT * from mybb_userfields where ufid = '$userid'";
$group4=mysql_query($group3) or die("Could not match userid");
while($raw=mysql_fetch_array($group4))
{
// assigns a lid from the vip members to the variable $lid
$lid = $raw['fid7'];
// Display the hash of the lid if it matches with the lid from the URL
if($lid == '')
{

}
elseif($lid == $id)
{
echo "[key]{$lid};";
}
else
{
}
}

}
```

Comment: `$usergroup` comes directly from user-supplied input, but you don't sanitize it. Please sanitize your input: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about `where usergroup AND ...` - is `usergroup` a DB field? Anyway, you could do it with

```
$group="SELECT * from mybb_users where usergroup AND FIND_IN_SET('$usergroup', additionalgroups) != 0;
```

But that is not enough yet. AFAICS you are vulnerable to SQL injection. Please use `mysql_real_escape()` at the right places, namely everywhere you put variables with user input into a SQL query.

Comment: Ok, `FIND_IN_SET()` is much better than my solution. But the injection stuff still applies...

Comment: i tried your method... it wouldn't work and yes usergroup is a DB column and $usergroup is just a variable that gets the [game] vaule from the URL

Comment: what means "wouldn't work"? What MySQL error is shown by `mysql_error()`? Or is the result set just empty?

Comment: i tried the find_in_set() 
here is my code

'$group =
" SELECT * 
  FROM mybb_users 
  WHERE usergroup = '$usergroup'
    AND FIND_IN_SET('$usergroup', additionalgroups)";
$group2=mysql_query($group) or die("Could not get users");
while($raw=mysql_fetch_array($group2))
{
// Fetch all UserIDs of the VIP members and match them with the UfID (in the userfields table)
$userid = $raw['uid'];
$group3="SELECT * from mybb_userfields where ufid = '$userid'";
$group4=mysql_query($group3) or die("Could not match userid");'

http://livedown.us/test/index.php?liveid={59d-e43021-4b4-d93a-8314}&game=8

Comment: i tried the find_in_set() here is my code:

    $group =
    " SELECT * 
  FROM mybb_users 
  WHERE usergroup = '$usergroup'
    AND FIND_IN_SET('$usergroup', additionalgroups)";
$group2=mysql_query($group) or die("Could not get users");
while($raw=mysql_fetch_array($group2))
{

$userid = $raw['uid'];
$group3="SELECT * from mybb_userfields where ufid = '$userid'";
$group4=mysql_query($group3) or die("Could not match userid");
while($raw=mysql_fetch_array($group4))    

 Still no luck: check this link: http://livedown.us/test/index.php?liveid={59d-e43021-4b4-d93a-8314}&game=8

Comment: you still have neither `mysql_real_escape()` nor `mysql_error()` in there. The latter could really help debugging...

Comment: nervermind... i made a silly mistake. In the query i had to use an OR instead of an AND... gosh i am an IDIOT!

Thanks for you help!

Answer (score 4):

On way to check is with the FIND_IN_SET function.

```
SELECT * from mybb_users where usergroup AND FIND_IN_SET('$usergroup', additionalgroups) != 0
```